# Ejecutar html en asp.net Core Web Applications (.Net framework)

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

Buenas tarde estoy trabajando con angular 1, asp.net Core Web Applications (.Net framework), lo cual que creado unos módulos y no he podido ejecutar la vista del login, y al ejecutar me sale `hello word` del startup.
no hay manera de decirle a visual que vista ejecutar o hay que configurar algo que me permita ejecutar la vista?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero te ayude en algo esta información:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html

http://benjii.me/2016/01/angular2-routing-with-asp-net-core-1/

http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/08/08/setup-angular2-typescript-aspnetcore-in-visualstudio.html

Answer (score 4):

En tu Startup.cs, en el void Configure, agrega esto:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Que se encuentra en el paquete:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
```

Esto va en el project.json

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

Comment: +1 Va doc relacionado [https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html] (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

Comment: gracias @JoseA.Fernandez por agregar el enlace :D